# Jquery Datatables is giving an error when clicking on a checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using jquery datatables plugin: https://www.datatables.net/download/index .. I have a table header that is generated using jquery. I added a checkbox to one of the columns of the table. Each time I click on that checkbox, I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'length' of false`

I went to look in the code for jquery and here is what I see in my console:

[image]

For reference, the function causing an error is:

```
function _fnSortListener ( settings, colIdx, append, callback )
    {
        var col = settings.aoColumns[ colIdx ];
        var sorting = settings.aaSorting;
        var asSorting = col.asSorting;
        var nextSortIdx;
        var next = function ( a, overflow ) {
            var idx = a._idx;
            if ( idx === undefined ) {
                idx = $.inArray( a[1], asSorting );
            }

            return idx+1 < asSorting.length ?
                idx+1 :
                overflow ?
                    null :
                    0;
        };

        // Convert to 2D array if needed
        if ( typeof sorting[0] === 'number' ) {
            sorting = settings.aaSorting = [ sorting ];
        }

        // If appending the sort then we are multi-column sorting
        if ( append && settings.oFeatures.bSortMulti ) {
            // Are we already doing some kind of sort on this column?
            var sortIdx = $.inArray( colIdx, _pluck(sorting, '0') );

            if ( sortIdx !== -1 ) {
                // Yes, modify the sort
                nextSortIdx = next( sorting[sortIdx], true );

                if ( nextSortIdx === null && sorting.length === 1 ) {
                    nextSortIdx = 0; // can't remove sorting completely
                }

                if ( nextSortIdx === null ) {
                    sorting.splice( sortIdx, 1 );
                }
                else {
                    sorting[sortIdx][1] = asSorting[ nextSortIdx ];
                    sorting[sortIdx]._idx = nextSortIdx;
                }
            }
            else {
                // No sort on this column yet
                sorting.push( [ colIdx, asSorting[0], 0 ] );
                sorting[sorting.length-1]._idx = 0;
            }
        }
        else if ( sorting.length && sorting[0][0] == colIdx ) {
            // Single column - already sorting on this column, modify the sort
            nextSortIdx = next( sorting[0] );

            sorting.length = 1;
            sorting[0][1] = asSorting[ nextSortIdx ];
            sorting[0]._idx = nextSortIdx;
        }
        else {
            // Single column - sort only on this column
            sorting.length = 0;
            sorting.push( [ colIdx, asSorting[0] ] );
            sorting[0]._idx = 0;
        }

        // Run the sort by calling a full redraw
        _fnReDraw( settings );

        // callback used for async user interaction
        if ( typeof callback == 'function' ) {
            callback( settings );
        }
    }
```

My table header looks like this:

[image]

This is my table definition:

```
[<div id=​"fulfillment_board_wrapper" class=​"dataTables_wrapper no-footer show-batch-select">​<div class=​"dataTables_scroll">​<div class=​"dataTables_scrollHead" style=​"overflow:​ hidden;​ position:​ relative;​ border:​ 0px;​ width:​ 100%;​">​…​</div>​<div class=​"dataTables_scrollBody" style=​"position:​ relative;​ overflow:​ auto;​ width:​ 100%;​ height:​ 550px;​">​…​</div>​</div>​</div>​
```

based on the suggestion below I used:

```
$('#fulfillment_board_wrapper').dataTable({"columnDefs": [{"orderable": false, targets:0}]})
```

inside my javascript file. However, i am still getting an error.

The checkbox to the left of **VIP** is causing the error.. How can I prevent this error from happening? How can I stop this listener from listening?

Comment: Have you tried to disable the sorting on that column?

Comment: @markpsmith, how do I disable sorting on it.. as this is something that jquery-datatables adds automatically

Comment: Yes, but you can disable it on a per-column basis: [https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable)

Comment: @markpsmith: I am adding this $('#fulfillment_board_wrapper').dataTable({"columnDefs": [{"orderable": false, targets:0}]}) in my javascript file. But continuing to see the error

Comment: Are you using v1.9? then that syntax won't work, see this [http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6006/disable-sorting](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6006/disable-sorting). You could try `"bSort" : false` which completely disables the table sorting, just to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @markpsmith please see my edited response above where I have shown my table definition. I tried this $('#fulfillment_board_wrapper').dataTable({
    "bSort" : false} ); but it still does not work. Do you know what I may be doing incorrectly

Comment: also @markpsmith I am using 1.10.9 version.. when I add the code above I get a dialog box that says:  DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (DIV). For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/2

Comment: Here is a simple working example where the first column sorting is disabled: [https://jsfiddle.net/markps/HEDvf/3178/](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/HEDvf/3178/)