# How to prevent click on "Select all" checkbox to affect header and column sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables plugin. I created a checkbox, that automatically got a `aria-label` tag.

I think this is causing undesired behaviour and I would like to define a checkbox which does not have this `aria-label` property.

```
<th id="batch-select-all" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="board" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 21px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending">
  <input type="checkbox">
</th>
```

I removed the `aria-label` value by using `$("#batch-select-all").removeAttr('aria-label');` but yet the event continues to be triggered.

How I can make this event listener stop listening to click event on the checkbox?

Comment: I suggest pasting the code inside this question, rather than posting a screen shot.

Comment: @HunterStevens I have done so.. now could you take a look?

Comment: What is the 'undesired behaviour'?

Comment: basically, the checkbox is not meant for sorting..it is meant to function as something that can be checked, to check the checkboxes below at once. as a result, it is throwing this error. Ideally i would like no sorting behaviour

Comment: @markpsmith do you know how I could define the checkbox such that it does not have this sorting behaviour

Comment: That's what you're asking here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038281/jquery-datatables-is-giving-an-error-when-clicking-on-a-checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038281/jquery-datatables-is-giving-an-error-when-clicking-on-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in `aria-label` attribute. Your code seems to be copied from source code inspector, these attributes are generated by jQuery DataTables dynamically.

> **SOLUTION #1**

You can disable sorting for the column with a checkbox, add `data-orderable="false"` attribute to `th` element as follows:

```
<th id="batch-select-all" data-orderable="false">
  <input type="checkbox">
</th>
```

Also, you can use [`columns.orderable`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable) option to disable ordering on particular column.

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo17ae4k/2/) for code and demonstration.

> **SOLUTION #2**

Alternatively, in your click event handler for the checkbox you need to call [`stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to avoid click event to propagate to table header.

```
$('#example thead th').on('click', '#select-all', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo17ae4k/) for code and demonstration.